# Why does the "drush status" command result in "Permission denied"?

Tags: drush, composer

I installed Drush via global Composer, and it seems that it should have installed correctly. However, when I executed `drush status` in terminal, it resulted in `Permission denied`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

---

More information:

`which drush` command outputted `/Users/marcello/.composer/vendor/bin/drush`.

Using `echo $PATH` on Drush outputted `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/marcello/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/marcello/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

I can run Drush in `vendor/drush/drush`, but not globally.